# Modelling a bitemporal data set in a data warehouse

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, entity-attribute-value, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a bitemporal EAV type model.

There are multiple attribute tables(one for each value data type(int_attributes, float_attributes, etc. )) looking like:

```
|id|field_id|value|as_of_date_start|as_of_date_end|system_date_start|system_date_end|
```

And a reference table for attributes:

```
|field_id|name|data_type|target_attribute_table|
```

It is possible to construct an entity and get all its attributes at any point in time by querying a union of all attribute value tables.

I want to move this data to a data warehouse(Snowflake). I wasn't able to find a whole lot of info on moving bitemporal data to a warehouse and how to model it. I don't understand where would I need a facts and dimensions related modelling in this scenario. Also would it make any sense to pivot this table to get attributes as columns when loading the data in the system?

The main use cases of this data is to get the current snapshot of data, and get entire history of some entities.

I'm very new to data modelling in a warehouse, any pointers/books/resources to understand this are also appreciated.

Comment: @bbaird last 20 years of data with 3000 different attributes that can be on any entity with new attrs being added any month.

Comment: I'd love to answer because I have a lot of experience with bitemporal data, however EAV is *not* a viable solution, especially for that volume of data.  Getting the time elements correct with that design pattern is 100% guaranteed to fail.

Comment: @bbaird Not a viable solution for a data warehouse model? It has been scaling pretty well till now for our OLTP use case as the system has been in production for 20 years now, with more than a million entities and 3000 attrs(though this is selective based on entity type and we have close to 200 attrs per entity).

Comment: It's one thing to query a tiny fraction of records with a single transaction.  If you're looking to query larger amounts of data you need to be more thoughtful in design.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake [claims](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html) to be efficient at querying semi-structured data. Dump your data in this format and import it to Snowflake. Keep specific columns for the keys and dates. Everything else - why you needed EAV - goes in the JSON.